# Decrypting Captive Portal Data

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wireshark, captive-portal

My university has a captive portal login. Each user is given a username and a password. For Wpa, if you go to Edit-> Preferences and type IEEE 802.11, you can decrypt wireshark data. How can i decrypt data that is on a captive portal? Since everyone has their own username and password to access the internet, data will also be encrypted in 802.11 frames right? If anything doesn't make sense, please ask? 
Thank You

Comment: [Didn't you ask this last week?](https://superuser.com/questions/1341238/decrypting-wifi-packets-on-a-public-hotspot)

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: it isn't the same question. Last time, i asked how to decrypt 802.11 frames without knowing the WPA password. Right now, i am at my university and they have a captive portal login. But, all i see "802.11" protocol on wireshark and i am asking how to decrypt data on a open network. Cause when i go to edit->preferences->IEEE 802.11 , i can decrypt data for WPA,WEP by supplying the password and getting the handshake, but what about captive portal logins. i didn't  find any way of decrypting any of the data cause all data is still "802.11 protocol" and i don't know where to  decrypt the data.

Comment: it isn't the same question. Last time, i asked how to decrypt 802.11 frames without knowing the WPA password. Right now, i am at my university and they have a captive portal login. But, all i see "802.11" protocol on wireshark and i am asking how to decrypt data on a open network. Cause when i go to edit->preferences->IEEE 802.11 , i can decrypt data for WPA,WEP by supplying the password and getting the handshake, but what about captive portal logins. i didn't  find any way of decrypting any of the data cause all data is still "802.11 protocol" and i don't know where to  decrypt the data.

Answer (score -1):

Captive portal networks almost never use 802.11-layer encryption. You’ll need to run a sniffer and capture your own captive portal session to see what higher-layer encryption, if any, is used. Then proceed from there once you know what you’re dealing with.